# Lightning component Jquery data table: After create and edit user need to stay on the same page

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, jquery, datatable

I am using Jquery data table in my lightning component. We have a EDIT Button to edit the record. Once the edit is done(suppose i am on the 2nd page), i want to stay in the same page(2nd page). But, it is going back to the First page. How to remain on the same page ?

I have tried to use : $('#productTable').DataTable({stateSave: true}); instead of 
$('#productTable').DataTable(), But got this error: DataTables warning: table id=productTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3.

http://datatables.net/tn/3: This document says that, 
Simply put, Data Tables does not allow initialization options to be altered at any time other than at initialization time. Any manipulation of the table after initialization must be done through the API and trying to set the initialization options once the table has already been initialized will result in the error:

Any help on this please. Below is my codes.

```
<aura:component controller="ProductModifyRequestController" access="global" 
            implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
<!-- START : Aura Handlers  -->
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<!-- END : Aura Handlers -->


<!-- START : Product Table-->

<aura:if isTrue="{!v.infoMessageUpload != null}">
    <span class="errorMsg">{!v.infoMessageUpload}</span>
</aura:if>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.resultInfoWrapper.dateInfo.isSuccess == false}">
    <span class="errorMsg">{!v.resultInfoWrapper.dateInfo.messageInfo}</span>
</aura:if>

<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.modifyRequestData.productPricingRequest))}">

    <div class="slds-box tableScroll">   
        <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider sectionHeader">
            {!$Label.c.Product_Result_Table}</h3>    
        <br/>
        <table  id="productTable" class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-max-medium-table_stacked-horizontal">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title--caps slds-line-height_reset">
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate"
                             title="{!$Label.c.Product_Code}">{!$Label.c.Product_Code}

                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate"
                             title="{!$Label.c.Product_Description}">{!$Label.c.Product_Description}

                        </div>
                    </th>

                     <th data-label="{!$Label.c.End_Date}" scope="row">
                              {!record.ValidToFormated__c}
                     </th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.currentList}"
                                var="record">
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Product_Code}" scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate">
                                <a href="" onclick="{!c.viewProductModal}"
                                   data-selectedindex="{!record.Id}">
                                    {!record.Material_Number__c}</a>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Product_Description}" scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                {!record.Name}
                            </div>
                        </th>

                        <th data-label="{!$Label.c.Btn_Edit}" scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate innerDiv">
                                <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" 
                                                  label="{!$Label.c.Btn_Edit}" 
                                                  onclick="{!c.openProductModal}"
                                                  name="{!record}"
                                                  aura:id="btnSave"/>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> 

</aura:if>
<!--END : Product Result Table-->

<!--START : Edit Product Popup-->
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.openModelCheckbox}">
   <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" aura:id="prodbox" class="slds-modal">
      <div class="slds-modal__container distributorModel">
          <div class="slds-modal__header">
             <img src="{!$Resource.CloseIcon}" 
                         class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse imgModel" 
                         title="{!$Label.c.Btn_Close}" 
                         onclick="{!c.closeModal}"/>
              <span class="slds-assistive-text">{!$Label.c.Btn_Close}</span>
           </div>

           <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
              <div>
                <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordProductEdit"
                                                  objectApiName="Product_Pricing_Request__c" 
                                                  recordId="{!v.productPricing.Id}"
                                                  onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                                                  onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}" 
                                                  onerror="{!c.handleError}">

                   <div class="slds-box">
                      <aura:if isTrue="{!v.infoMessageEdit != null}">
                        <span class="errorMsgColor">{!v.infoMessageEdit}</span>
                      </aura:if>
                      <aura:if isTrue="{!v.errorMessageEdit}">
                        <span class="errorMsgColor">{!$Label.c.Mandatory_Message}</span>
                      </aura:if>

                      <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider sectionHeader">
                            {!$Label.c.Update_Product_Details}</h3>

                      <lightning:layout >
                            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">
                                <div class="header-column">
                                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
                                        <label for="prodCodeEdit">{!$Label.c.Product_Code}</label>

                                        <lightning:input variant="label-hidden" 
                                                         value="{!v.productPricing.Material_Number__c}" 
                                                         type="text" 
                                                         aura:id="prodCodeEdit" 
                                                         disabled="true" />                                                               


                                       </div>
                                     </div>
                              </lightning:layoutItem>

                              <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">
                                 <div class="header-column">
                                    <div class="slds-text-body_regular">


                                       <span class="">{!$Label.c.Requested_End_Date}</span>
                                        <span class="errorMsgColor">*</span>
                                        <lightning:inputField fieldName="Valid_To__c"
                                                              variant="label-hidden"
                                                              value="{!v.productPricing.Valid_To__c}" 
                                                              aura:id="reqEndDate"/>


                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                                </lightning:layoutItem>
                         </lightning:layout>

                 <div align="center">
                   <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" type="submit" name="save" label="{!$Label.c.Btn_Save}"/>              
                 </div> 

             </div>  
           </lightning:recordEditForm>
         </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop " aura:id="prodEndBox"></div>
</aura:if>    
<!--END : Edit Product Popup-->

controller.Js:
({ 
   doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
      helper.getProduct(component, event);        
   },

   openProductModal: function(component,event,helper) {
    component.set("v.openModelCheckbox",true);
    component.set("v.resultInfoWrapper.messageInfo", '');
    var currentRecord = event.getSource().get("v.name");
    component.set("v.productPricing", currentRecord);
    var cmpTarget = component.find('prodbox');
    var cmpBack = component.find('prodEndBox');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpBack, 'slds-backdrop--open'); 
},

   handleSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
      event.preventDefault();   
      var fields = event.getParam('fields');
      component.find('recordProductEdit').submit(fields); // submit/save in db
   },
   handleSuccess: function(component, event, helper){
      helper.displayUpdatedProduct(component, event); 
   },
})


 Helper.Js:
({
    getProduct: function (component, event) {
        var action = component.get("c.getRecordDetails");
        action.setParams({
            "pricingAgreementRequestId": component.get("v.priceAgreementRequestId")
        });

        console.log('Product method triggtreed');
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.resultInfoWrapper", response.getReturnValue());
                var records = component.get("v.modifyRequestData.productPricingRequest");
                if (records != null) {
                 component.set("v.currentList", records);
                }
                   console.log('Product action init method triggtreed');
                 setTimeout(function(){ 
                     try{
                       $('#productTable').DataTable({stateSave: true}); - This line
                       $('div.dataTables_filter input').addClass('slds-input');
                       $('div.dataTables_filter input').css("marginBottom", "10px");
                    }catch(e){
                        alert(e);
                    }

                    console.log('Product init DataTable method triggtreed');
                    },500);
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError(); 
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        component.set("v.errorVal", true);
                    }
                } else {
                    component.set("v.errorVal", true);
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
},



displayUpdatedProduct: function (component, event) {

    //Display the Updated data in product table, Query from the Db.
    var action = component.get("c.getProductPricingRequest");
    action.setParams({
       "pricingAgreementRequestId": component.get("v.priceAgreementRequestId")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
       var state = response.getState();
       if (state === "SUCCESS") {

          var records =  response.getReturnValue();
          if (records != null) {

            component.set("v.modifyRequestData.productPricingRequest", records); // Table column display

             if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#productTable') ) {
                   var table = $('#productTable').DataTable();   
                   table.destroy();
             }
             this.getProduct(component, event);------------- To initialize the table with updated value
             this.closeDisModal(component, event); 

             //Success toast !!
              var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
              toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Success!",
                "message": $A.get("$Label.c.PriceAgreementRecordSaveSucessMessage") 
              });
              toastEvent.fire(); 
           }
         }

      else if (state === "ERROR") {
         var errors = response.getError();
         if (errors) {
                  if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    component.set("v.errorVal", true);
                  }
         }
         else {
                 component.set("v.errorVal", true);
         }
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  },
```

Comment: are you saying the record edit  form that you are displaying on modal it takes you to some other screen after clicking on save,if not which two page are you talking about?

Comment: Page in the sense , pagination which is coming with Jquery data table.